# how to implements addEventListener in iron form polymer

Tags: polymer

How to implements addEventListener in iron form polymer?

i already following this guide : [iron-form](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-form)

and this is my code :

```
<form is="iron-form" method="get" action="/" id="eventsDemo">
  <paper-input name="name" label="Name" required auto-validate></paper-input>
  <paper-input name="password" label="Password" type="password" required auto-validate></paper-input>
  <paper-checkbox name="read" required>You must check this box</paper-checkbox><br>
  <paper-button raised onclick="_delayedSubmit(event)" disabled id="eventsDemoSubmit">
  <paper-spinner id="spinner" hidden></paper-spinner>Submit</paper-button>
  <paper-button raised onclick="_reset(event)">Reset</paper-button>
  <div class="output"></div>
</form>
<script>
  eventsDemo.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    // Validate the entire form to see if we should enable the `Submit` button.
    eventsDemoSubmit.disabled = !eventsDemo.validate();
  });
  function _delayedSubmit(event) {
    spinner.active = true;
    spinner.hidden = false;
    eventsDemoSubmit.disabled = true;
    // Simulate a slow server response.
    setTimeout(function() {
      Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
    }, 1000);
  }
  function _reset(event) {
    var form = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement
    form.reset();
    form.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = '';
  }
  document.getElementById('eventsDemo').addEventListener('iron-form-submit', function(event) {
    spinner.active = false;
    spinner.hidden = true;
    eventsDemoSubmit.disabled = false;
    this.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.detail);
  });
</script>
```

my form id 'eventsDemo' not defined, why?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: eventsDemo is not defined
```

Comment: Is this in HTML or another custom element? How about `var eventsDemo = document.getElementById('eventsDemo')` or use `this.$.eventsDemo` in case of the latter?

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz I bet it's *not* a custom element given that there is no `<template>` or `Polymer({ is: 'x-foo' })` :)

Answer (score 1):

The `eventsDemo` variable is not yet declared in your JS. I see you have an element with `id="eventsDemo"`, but that does not automatically declare a variable for use in the `<script>` tag.

To fetch an element by its identifier, you could use either [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) in `<script>`:

```
var eventsDemo = document.getElementById('eventsDemo');
var eventsDemo = document.querySelector('#eventsDemo');
```

Comment: hi @tony19, when i try it eventsDemo is "null" and now the error change into "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: @monoysuronoy, Can you provide a demo (codepen, jsfiddle, jsbin, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for that link, but it still shows the original code and not what you've tried.

Comment: Yes, we're working towards that. :) You stated: `when i try it eventsDemo is "null"`, so I'd like to see what you tried.

Comment: on the code, button submit form must be enable when form all filled